# Can't deploy React app to Heroku due to webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, heroku, webpack

I'm trying to deploy a react app (not Create-react-app), which consist of my own webpack configurations. I can Build the app successfully locally and running locally successfully. But when I push to Heroku, `git push heroku master` I get the following message:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        YARN_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  10.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        engines.yarn (package.json):  1.x
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 10.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.16.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.9.0
remote:        Resolving yarn version 1.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing yarn (1.16.0)...
remote:        Installed yarn 1.16.0
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Caching has been disabled because NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
remote:        yarn install v1.16.0
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 18.83s.
remote:
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build (yarn)
remote:        yarn run v1.16.0
remote:        $ rm -rf build/ && webpack --env.mode production
remote:
remote: Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
remote: Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.
remote:
remote:        Hash: 9809f658cd5ff48864d7
remote:        Version: webpack 4.33.0
remote:        Time: 555ms
remote:        Built at: 06/12/2019 9:16:13 PM
remote:
remote:        ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/tmp/build_429e145805178d81754292048e646eab'
remote:        Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
remote:             1 asset
remote:            Entrypoint undefined = index.html
remote:            [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html 1.9 KiB {0} [built]
remote:            [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
remote:            [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
remote:                + 1 hidden module
remote: error Command failed with exit code 2.
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to react-go-fullstack.
remote:
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "fullstack-course",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rm -rf build/ && webpack-dev-server --env.mode development --hot",
    "build": "rm -rf build/ && webpack --env.mode production"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x",
    "yarn": "1.x"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/NaseebullahSafi/fullstack-course/issues"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.7.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.8.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resources-manifest-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
  }
}
```

Can someone please explain what the issue is, and how can one resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: Error is "remote:        ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/tmp/build_429e145805178d81754292048e646eab'. Follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538466/error-cannot-resolve-module-babel-loader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Cannot resolve module 'babel-loader'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538466/error-cannot-resolve-module-babel-loader)